# How can I write my IEqualityComparer without checking for nulls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm running my project in a nullable enabled context and I wish to simplify my code because it's internal and I KNOW that the references passed in are non-null. The IEqualityComparer interface gives warnings if I make the parameters not nullable.

```
class FileInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    // Round up timestamp to the next 2 seconds
    const long interval = 20_000_000;
    DateTime RoundUp(DateTime time) => time.AddTicks(interval - (time.Ticks - 1) % interval - 1);

    public bool Equals(FileInfo? fi1, FileInfo? fi2)
    {
        return fi1.Name == fi2.Name &&
            RoundUp(fi1.LastWriteTime) == RoundUp(fi2.LastWriteTime) && fi1.Length == fi2.Length;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FileInfo fi)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(fi.Name, RoundUp(fi.LastWriteTime), fi.Length);
    }
}
```

As it stands I'm getting squigglies under various fi1 and fi2 references whenever I try to make them not nullable. I've tried adding various attributes like [NotNull] in places but nothing works. I've also tried writing like this:

```
return fi1?.Name == fi2?.Name &&
    RoundUp(fi1.LastWriteTime) == RoundUp(fi2.LastWriteTime) && i1.Length == fi2.Length;
```

but the squigglies just move somewhere else. Are there any Null attributes like [DisallowNull] etc. that I can add in the right places to remove the warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/// <remarks>
/// <see cref="Equals"/> rejects <see langword="null"/> values.
/// </remarks>
class FileInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    // Other parts as before

    public bool Equals(FileInfo? fi1, FileInfo? fi2)
    {
        if (fi1 is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fi1));
        }

        if (fi2 is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fi2));
        }

        return fi1.Name == fi2.Name &&
            RoundUp(fi1.LastWriteTime) == RoundUp(fi2.LastWriteTime) && fi1.Length == fi2.Length;
    }

    // GetHashCode as before
}
```

It is possible to make the argument validation a single line if desired by turning it into a method that takes a parameter and throws if it is null.

Alternative using the null forgiving operator:

```
/// <remarks>
/// <see cref="Equals"/> rejects <see langword="null"/> values.
/// </remarks>
class FileInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    // Other parts as before

    public bool Equals(FileInfo? fi1, FileInfo? fi2)
    {
        return fi1!.Name == fi2!.Name &&
            RoundUp(fi1.LastWriteTime) == RoundUp(fi2.LastWriteTime) && fi1.Length == fi2.Length;
    }

    // GetHashCode as before
}
```

Comment: I was rather hoping to keep the original code and add some of those attributes regarding the nullability features they added in C#8.0 to rid of the warnings. It may be possible that's why I'm asking here. I don't need the null checks in my internal class and at the same time I want to keep the nullability context for the project as a whole. Also I don't want to resort to suppressing the warnings.

Comment: In that case you probably want the null forgiving operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving